My springboot application is not able to run swagger UI on localhost
I have integrated swagger in my springboot application through following dependency.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

I have also allowed swagger URL in my security configurations as following:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {

        try {
            return http
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
                                "/api/users/register", "/api/users/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/users/{id}").hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/users/{id}").hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/users/{id}").hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/transactions").hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/transactions/{id}").hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/transactions/{id}").hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/transactions/{id}").hasRole("USER")
                    )
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

Following is my application.properties.
spring.application.name=Fintech-Backend-Developer-Assignment
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

But still when I run the URL http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html, I get following error.


Which spring boot version?

Also, why are you permitting POST to "/swagger-ui/**"? You would definitely need GET to open it in a browser. Also, I think you will need to permit /v3/api-docs.

Try disabling csrf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64837907/2213003

@ILyaCyclone it is 3.2.5

@ILyaCyclone that I had already corrected, I have updated the question. kindly look at updated question.

You should open "/swagger-ui/index.html" in a browser with dev tools/network opened. I believe, you will see a failed request to "/v3/api-docs". This is where by default openapi specification generated file is situated. Swagger-ui is built from that file. Since you haven't permitted anonymous access to "/v3/api-docs", swagger-ui fails to load.
In that case you should permit "/v3/api-docs" as well as "/swagger-ui/**" in your security config.
Some docs from springdoc site.

https://springdoc.org/#getting-started:


The Swagger UI page will then be available at http://server:port/context-path/swagger-ui.html and the OpenAPI description will be available at the following url for json format: http://server:port/context-path/v3/api-docs


https://springdoc.org/#springdoc-openapi-core-properties:


Parameter name: springdoc.api-docs.path
Default Value: /v3/api-docs
Description: String, For custom path of the OpenAPI documentation in Json format.

